# postgres function flexible query return

Tags: function, postgresql-9.4

What is a flexible way to create a function returning multiple rows?
Im in development of a pg9.4 database, and it is not uncommon to modify the number of columns in the SELECT statements in my functions. 
However, as Ive learned plpgsql the RETURNS is specified as SETOF .  Which is fine as long as the SELECT is a * or specifies all the table's columns in the query.

Is there a way to tell the RETURNS to use a SETOF the columns in the SELECT statement, or something along those lines? I saw that I
could use RETURNS TABLE [return multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027965/return-select-result-in-postgres-function) , but I was hoping for something more dynamic.
Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE business
(
  retailerid integer NOT NULL,
  retailername character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkretailerid PRIMARY KEY (retailerid)
)
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
INSERT INTO business(retailerid, retailername)
VALUES(1,'Mc Donalds');
INSERT INTO business(retailerid, retailername)
VALUES(2,'Burger King');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getretailers()
  RETURNS SETOF business AS
$BODY$
 BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT retailerid, retailername FROM business;
 END
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;

SELECT getretailers(); -- works
drop function getretailers();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getretailers()
  RETURNS SETOF business AS
$BODY$
 BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT retailername FROM business;
 END
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
SELECT getretailers(); -- err, structure of query does not match return type
```

Comment: You will need to add some examples - I for one have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: setof expects more than one field to be returned.

Comment: @mcNets that may be, but I dont believe its the issue here.  SETOF requires that you specify some type of schema (table, view) that exactly (except for *) matches the select statement columns.  Or you can use TABLE, which is sort of an in-function schema.  I was hoping for a way the return schema is automatically derived from the select columns. Thx!